# Fix header and footer to top and bottom of window, scrolling content only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make both the header/footer position fixed to the top/bottom of the window and only scroll the middle content.
I tried fixed position on the containers as well as overflow-y on the content for no avail.  Any suggestion?

Thanks

```css
header,
footer {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: #d9d8da;
}
footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
header label:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
}
header label:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 6.5em);
  text-align: center;
}
header label:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
  padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" />
  <title>RRR</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <label>&#9776;</label>
    <label>My app</label>
    <label>&#8942;</label>

  </header>

  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>NO</li>
      <li>EXTRA</li>
      <li>YES</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to also add `width: 100%;` to header and footer in my previous answer. Here's your code modified:

```css
html, body { 
  heigth: 100%; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header,
footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: #d9d8da;
}
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 2em;
}
.content {
  padding: 2em 0;
 }
footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
header label:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
}
header label:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 6.5em);
  text-align: center;
}
header label:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
  padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" />
  <title>RRR</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <label>&#9776;</label>
    <label>My app</label>
    <label>&#8942;</label>

  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>NO</li>
      <li>EXTRA</li>
      <li>YES</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The footer in your solution is cut half way vertically.

Comment: @FredJ. The footer isn't, that's the strange formatting of the ul in it (yours). I answered your question, I won't code your website for you....

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do my best to find out what to fix the in the ul you referred to. :)

Comment: reset ul margins and padding, adjust height and font sizes etc. - you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

add `position: fixed;` to both header and footer.

For the footer, also add "bottom: 0px`

and  your content should have top and bottom margins high enough to cover the space of those fixed elements when it's scrolled all the way up or down.

Comment: Just by adding position: fixed; to the first block which is header, footer, in the css file and footer "bottom; 0px" as you suggested distorted the view too bad to describe it here. Could you please show you solution in code?

Comment: see my new answer + code (actually both answers belong together)